# Missing App icon in Sticker Pack, but i have all icons set

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have all my icons sized to what Xcode tells me, and placed them in the correct positions.  When i go to validate in Archive, it says "Missing App Icon, The bundle doesn't contain an iMessage app icon.  iMessage app icons must be 120x90 pixels in .png format."

this is my first time trying to upload an app and can't seem to find a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all **icons are in .png format** or not. If any image is **not in .png format convert that image into .png format** then **replace with existing one.** Then **Clean the project**, Then try to archive and then validate.

Answer (score -1):

Please check your icon sizes. Also re-check the 2x and 3x image sizes. And it should be in png formate.